# Get list of all apps

Tags: android, flutter

How can I get a list of all android apps (not including system apps)? Also how can I get this quick actions you can normaly get by long pressing the app icon.

Comment: In stackoverflow it's accepted to ask about one thing in one question. To ask about something else, make another question

Answer (score 2):

To get apps list from flutter, try [device apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps) plugin:

```
List<Application> apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(
    onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true,
    includeSystemApps: false,
);
```